# Angular2 twoway databinding issue

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bind an `input` control to the zoom property of a third party control map in a two-way databinding way (the input should always show the current zoom level and if the user changes it, the map should zoom to this level)

Currently, it only works in one direction: changes to the input box are not applied to the mapview.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'map-view',
    template: '<div id="mapView"></div><input [(value)]=zoom />'
})
export class MapViewComponent {
    view: any = null;

    public zoom: number = 10;


    constructor(private _mapService: SimpleMapService, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.view = new MapView({
            container: this.elRef.nativeElement.firstChild,
            map: this._mapService.map,
            zoom: this.zoom,
            center: [10.44, 42.947974]        
        })

        this.view.watch('zoom', function(newVal, oldVal, propertyName) {
            this.zoom = newVal;
        }.bind(this));    

    }

}
```

EDIT:
So I added

`<input [(ngModel)]="zoom"  (ngModelChange)="updateZoom($event)">`  to the input

and

```
updateZoom(newValue) {
   this.view.zoom = newValue;
}
```

to the component

and it seems to be working. But is that really the way it's supposed to be done? In Angular1, it did work with `$scope.$apply` without any events.

Comment: You can also use arrow functions to retain the scope of `this` `this.view.watch('zoom', (newVal, oldVal, propertyName) => {
            this.zoom = newVal;
        };` I think this makes the code shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Angular2 doesn't use 2-way binding for performance reasons. See also my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460810/angular-2-do-we-need-avoid-two-way-databind-when-not-necessary

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you. How could I have missed that.

Comment: Yup, it's an essential part of Angular2

Answer (score 1):

Try this `<input [(value)]="zoom"`;   //<-----added double quotes around zoom

OR

What about using `<input [(ngModel)]="zoom" >` ?

Comment: The quotes shouldn't be necessary if the expression doesn't contain spaces or special characters. The problem is that there is no `valueChange` event. This is why `[(value)]=...` doesn't work. Therefore your 2nd suggestion is point-on.

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated my post in reaction to your suggestion with the value change event.